# 2D line not showing clearly along with surface on 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a 1D line along with a 2D surface in matplotlib with Axes3D:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.arange(-1., 1.1, 0.1)
y = x.copy()
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.abs(X) + np.abs(Y)

plt.close('all')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot(np.zeros_like(y), y, 1, color='k')
ax.plot(x, np.zeros_like(x), 1, color='k')

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, color='w')

plt.show(block=False)
```

but the 2D plot somehow hides the lines:

[image]

If I comment the `surf = plot_surface(...)` code line, the 1D lines show correctly:
[image: If I comment the <code>surf =</code> code line]

How can I have the lines showing correctly along with the surface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Axes3D.plot_surface()` apparently accepts a transparency (`alpha`) argument, which actually gets forwarded to a base class, Poly3DCollection.

And of course the line `plot()` calls accept a `linewidth` argument.

So if you render the line plots with thicker lines and you render the surface with some transparency, you should be able to find a combination of settings which let you see both the lines and the surface in a balanced way.

https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/toolkits/mplot3d.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.plot_surface

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection

Comment: Using `alpha=0.5` in the plot_surface line makes it work. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve this by using the `zorder` in the `plot_surface` and `plot` commands to make the lines sit on top of the surface. E.g.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-1., 1.1, 0.1)
y = x.copy()
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.abs(X) + np.abs(Y)

plt.close('all')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, color='w', zorder=1)

ax.plot(np.zeros_like(y), y, 1, color='k', zorder=10)
ax.plot(x, np.zeros_like(x), 1, color='k', zorder=11)


plt.show(block=False)
```

[image]